# JQuery Get all parent nodes of selected Kendo Treeview

Tags: jquery, kendo-treeview

I have a kendoui treeview populated by nested values. When a user selected a particular node, I need to get the text from all the parent nodes above the selected node.

This is what i tried, but it returns me only the text from selected node, can you help? Thanks.

```
$( "#col1" ).on( "click", ".k-in", function() {
    cur_text = $(this).text();
    cur_text += $(this).parentsUntil( $(".k-top"), ".k-in" ).text();
    alert(cur_text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example, you can retrieve all `parents()` on the element selected:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <p>
        <span>
            <b>My parents are: </b>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var parentEls = $( "b" ).parents()
    .map(function() {
        return this.tagName;
    })
    .get()
    .join( ", " );

$( "b" ).append( "<strong>" + parentEls + "</strong>" );
```

If you print parentEls:

```
SPAN, P, DIV, BODY, HTML
```

After, you can truncate before to remove parent that you don't want and just stop at the root of your three